# What security issues next.js talks about for next/image?

Tags: next.js

In [next.js docs for next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#remote-patterns) it's said:

> To protect your application from malicious users, configuration is required in order to use external images. This ensures that only external images from your account can be served from the Next.js Image Optimization API.

I'm trying to understand what security issues it solves. I can't find anything in the docs.

Can anyone please explain that?